# Error submitting app via XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit an app tonight and I can validate the app find but when I go to submit, get the following errors:

`Apple's web service operation was not successful`

`Unable to Authenticate the package`

`exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload`

Has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: I just got the same error.  Maybe their servers are experiencing temporary issues?

Comment: Now I am facing the same problem... https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3822193?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3822193?start=0&tstart=0 Check this out.

Comment: for me worked resubmitting immediately after had this error

Comment: This is Apple's phone number for iTunesConnect, they are happy to listen to you vent over any frustrations that you might have with this program: +1 (800) 633-2152

Answer (score 20):

Just had this happen on Xcode 7. Quit Xcode, opened it back up, resubmitted and it worked fine.

EDIT: I agree with @arlomedia in the comments, this is a problem on Apple's side. Just had it happen again and restarting did not fix it. Maybe I just got lucky the first time :)

Comment: It might be a problem on Apple's end, because I had the problem at exactly the same time as you. Anyway, it also worked for me after restarting Xcode.

Comment: Same issue for me happening 2 hours after you guys posted.  I restarted Xcode, but the problem is still there.  Guess I have to wait for Apple to fix on their side.

Comment: Definitely apple server issue. Same error here for the past an hour

Comment: Mine actually didn't go through before ... it got past the point where the error occurred, but then ran for a long time and timed out. Then when I tried again I kept getting the error. However, I just tried a few minutes ago and it finally submitted.

Answer (score 14):

That seems like a temporary issue from Apple's side. It should have been fixed by now. Try uploading again.

Comment: Correct.  It works this morning!

Comment: I got this error in the morning before rushing out the door. Came home later and clicked Upload to App Store... again and it worked. No restart needed.

Answer (score 9):

I saw a slightly different error message, six times in a row:

```
Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004)
```

Restarted my mac, resubmitted and boom - worked.

Can't say for sure if it was the restart, could have just been something on Apple's servers as the other answers point out.

Comment: Just restart the Application Loader will help

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting it for several days until I changed Deployment Target from 3.1.3 to 4.3.

My error also said "The bundle does not contain icon for iPad exactly '72x72' pixels". I checked the icon and updated it like 5 times :)