# Error submitting app to iTunesConnect

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to update my application but xcode 7 and application loader give me same strange error i have not seen before.

`Exception occurred when creating MZContentProviderUpload for provider. (1004)`

Any ideas how to fix this? was not able to find anything that would help.

Comment: I will repeat my previous answer since Brad Larson has seen fit to delete it with no reason given.Same problem here for the last hour or so. Apparently, the problem has existed for at least 3 years. Reading through other forums, it appears the problem goes away after awhile. Hope so, I'm up to 15 attempts and it keeps failing.

Comment: same story. i gave up for today, will try again tomorrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem and all my research points to an Apple server issue even though Apple reports everything as up https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

This SO answer from 2012 covers it. 
[Error submitting app via XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695177/error-submitting-app-via-xcode)

Comment: I find that apple's system page always shows everything as up, even when I've had problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. Been this way for over 30 minutes. I've tried uploading multiple times.

From [this twitter](https://twitter.com/mike3k/status/657696877161267201) post, it looks like waiting for Apple to fix their end is the only thing that can be done.

https://twitter.com/mike3k/status/657696877161267201

### Update

As [someone on Apple dev forums pointed out](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25315), "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" in iTC say's "System maintenance in progress". This could be related to the error we are seeing...

[image: maintenance]